# Setting EMAIl ID on Microsite for %%ftaf_url%%

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, microsites

I have a microsite that has a Forward-to-a-Friend (`%%ftaf_url%%`) function.

- Can I set the specific EMAIL ID to forward on the microsite and override the EMAIL ID set from the incoming link?
- Can I set the EMAIL ID on the referenced link using `%%=RedirectTo(MicrositeURL())=%%`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
%%=RedirectTo(MicrositeURL(123, "emailid", _emailid))=%%
```

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the variable used. I used the code you provided but it still forwarded the parent email instead of the one I passed through `%%=RedirectTo(MicrositeURL(123, "emailid", _emailid))=%%` function..

Comment: Is `_emailid` the correct variable name?

Comment: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/ (under Data About the Recipient).

Comment: Thanks Victor. It seems that setting the _emailid through the MicrositeURL() function does not override the original _emailid.